# Puppeteer - Unable to launch more than 2 browsers

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

Hi I have a simple puppeteer script that uses a different `userDataDir` per instance.

I'm unable to spawn more than 2 instances of puppeteer.

Here's the code:

```
ipcMain.on('request-mainprocess-action', (event, arg) => {
    var taskData = arg[0];
    var url = taskData[5];
    var headlessChoice = arg[0][11];
    var taskName = taskData[21];

    var browserArgs = [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--window-size=1920x1080',
      '--lang=en-US,en',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--no-zygote',
      '--renderer-process-limit=1',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--ignore-certificate-errors',
      '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--allow-insecure-localhost',
      '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
    ];

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            userDataDir: tasksDataDirPath+'\\'+taskName,
            headless: headlessChoice,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            executablePath : arg[0][23],
            args: browserArgs,
            timeout: 3600000
        });
    
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const pagesArray = await browser.pages();
        pagesArray[0].close();

        await page.emulateTimezone("Asia/Singapore");

        if(headlessChoice == true){
          await page.setViewport({width: (width/2)-21, height: height-111});
        }
        
        if(headlessChoice == true){
          await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 3600000 });
        }
        else{
          await page.goto("https://bot.sannysoft.com/", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 3600000 });
        }
    
        await new Promise(resolve => { });
    })();
});
```

I'm able to only start `2` Instances, on the 3rd instance it just loads a blank page.

I'm also aware of puppeteer-cluster however I realize that with puppeteer-cluster i'm unable to set the `userDataDir`, so i'll have to use normal puppeteer :(

Anyone able to help?